# Define a custom WPF control with inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a simple problem I guess. Basically I have a `WPF` app, where I use `DataGrid` control a lot. And everytime I style it the same way (just the data, number of rows and columns are different). So I thought about creating my own control `DataGridMatrix` which would fill my needs.

The code I wrote for it is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StateMachines.UI.Controls.DataGridMatrix"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DataGrid Width="450"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.657,1.249"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Logic.DefaultView}" ColumnWidth="*"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Column.DisplayIndex}"
                        Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Block.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

So as you can see, I only style it, I don't put any data in it (in XAML). The problem is I can of course put this control in my `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```
<controls:DataGridMatrix x:Name="DataGridTransition"/>
```

But then, if I want f.e change the position (in grid, f.e I would like it to be `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` instead of `Grid.ColumnSpan="1") I can't do that, cuz the`DataGrid`is in my control, and my control isn't derived from`DataGrid` itself (I guess, if it would be derived, then I could do that, like in normal classes, right?).

So finally my question would be: Is there a way to inherit from a standard `XAML` control in my own `UserControl` and just style it differently (like here, in my code I would omit the `<DataGrid>` tag and I would place its arguments in `<UserControl>` tag + the other things like `DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle` would be placed right below the `<UserControl>`)?

Comment: Instead of making a custom control, you could try making a Style based on the DataGrid. That way, you could use the style, and still alter some properties of the grid.

Comment: Create a custom DataGrid instead of a custom UserControl.

Comment: @LupuSilviu So if I wanted to have 3 `DataGrid`s, I would just do 3x `<DataGrid></DataGrid>` and then somewhere above them I define I style that affects all the `DataGrid`s? @mm8 -> How would I create it? I mean `Add->New Item` and then what?

Comment: @Frynio: Just remove the `<UserControl>` root element and inherit the partial class from `DataGrid`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `DataGrid` instead of a custom `UserControl`, i.e remove the `<UserControl>` root element from your XAML file (`DataGridMatrix.xaml`) so it looks like this:

```
<DataGrid    x:Class="WpfApp2.DataGridMatrix"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="450"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.657,1.249"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Logic.DefaultView}" ColumnWidth="*"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRowHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Column.DisplayIndex}"
                        Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Block.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

...and change the base class in the code-behind (`DataGridMatrix.xaml.cs`) from `UserControl` to `DataGrid`:

```
public partial class DataGridMatrix : DataGrid
{
    public DataGridMatrix()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhmm. And if I don't have the `*.xaml.cs` file? Cuz I did `Add->New Item->WPF Control`? Should I add it manually?

Comment: You should have a DataGridMatrix.xaml.cs file if you have a x:Class attribute in your XAML...which you have in the sample markup you have posted.

Comment: Gee, I am so stupid. Didn't notice the arrow near the file name. Anyway, thank you, I think this will work for me, I can't check right know, cuz I am nowhere near my computer, but definitely will accept your answer. Thank you once more